# What is the latest Windows Azure library that I can use with VS2012?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am very confused. I had the 1.6 library and then upgraded to 1.7.

Now I see the following:

```
Windows Azure SDK for Windows 8 and .NET 4(2.0.0.0)
```

Is this the latest library and is it just for Windows 8?  I'm sorry but it's not very clear. When I try to download that it takes me to a web page with a link to download and no application. When I try for help it points me to stackoverflow.

Comment: The best way to ensure you install the latest is to use the web platform installer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows Azure SDK for Windows 8 and .NET 4 (2.0.0.0)
```

is probably

```
October 2012 Release (Version 1.8)
```

which is the latest release as of now (2012-12-04).

The version scheme changed a bit (e.g. storage client dll is now 2.0 because of breaking changes) while other parts remain unchanged/compatible (1.7/1.8) (see [Windows Azure SDK and Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg441573.aspx)).

The azure SDKs/client libraries should not depend on Windows 8.

You can find all downloads at [windowsazure.com](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/)